# How to deny execution of a file although allow deletion of it (XCACLS/ICACLS)

Tags: windows, icacls

Very frustrating problem, as the title suggests, I am trying to deny the user from executing the file, although I want to allow them to be able to delete the file

```
icacls bat.exe /grant *S-1-1-0:(D) /deny *S-1-1-0:(RX,WDAC)
```

I have tried a good few combinations, but having no luck :(

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Anyone? I am really stuck

Comment: Only been 15 minutes. Give it some time

Comment: @Nixphoe Shall do, very new to these Q&A sites :)

Comment: icacls bat.exe /deny *S-1-1-0:(X)

Answer (score 1):

You just need to use /deny and X.

i.e.:

```
icacls bat.exe /deny *S-1-1-0:(X)
```

This will allow a user to delete the file but not execute it.